# Media library and posts list problems with Wordpress on IIS

Tags: media-library, iis

I have Wordpress 3.5 installed on IIS7 and I'm using SQL Server instead of MySql. Some strange "glitches" occur and I think their related to the same problem.

1. I cannot see media library items on the first page. If I'll go to ~/upload.php?paged=2 I am able to see all the media. It basically starts to show the items from the second page.
2. The same problem occurs with the posts list. If I'm going to another page in the posts category, I am able to see them.
3. Settings/Permalinks throws and internal server error, so I can't check what's there even if I'm not sure if I would be able to change permalinks from there.

Any ideas are appreciated, I'm curious what's the reason for the first two points.

Update: for point 3, the detailed error sounds like this:

```
C:\Program Files\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly
Handler PHP53_via_FastCGI
Error Code  0x00000001
```

Comment: What are the logs saying about point 3?

Comment: +1 Or simply turn the full debugging env on and tell us about the output.

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: Corresponding to your error message. Check folders permision. Check if correct php.ini loads. Check location of the extension dir, it should be the same as you have in php.ini.

Comment: Without the correct php.ini and the correct path for the extentions dir I wouldn't be able to access the dashboard at all.

Comment: did you ever find a solution on this?

Comment: it was a small bug in the plugin used for MSSQL compatibility (I don't remember how was it called); can't remember a lot of useful details, but it went on to becoming a great company story

Answer (score 0):

To correct work of permalinks on IIS you should install http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Also take a look on complete guide http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/install-wordpress-on-iis

Comment: I installed it following that guide and I have url rewrite installed.